# Put files in bundle into specific folder locations on iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle, nsfilemanager

The files inside of my app bundle are arranged into folders, but when I check the file layout of the bundle, it seems these files are all added to the same directory, and not sorted by folder as I have them in XCode. How can I make sure they're added to the device in the same folder structure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The folders created in Xcode using "**Group**" or "**Group from Selection**" (yellow folders) are not true *Folders*, but *Groups*. They are only a visual way to organize your sources.

To make true folders (blue), create them on disk (using, say, the Finder).
You can then import them into Xcode using the option "**Create folder references for any added folders**".

*In short:*

1. Groups (yellow). Not related to the actual file/folder layout
2. Folders (blue). Direct representation of the OS hierarchy

Comment: Where is this option? "Create folder references for any added folders".